VS Code task: /bin/bash won't run alias
I have the following VSCode task:
    {
        "label": "gen-and-dep",
        "type": "shell",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/child_folder"
        },
        "command": "source ~/folder/env.sh && sdk generate",
        "group": "build"
    },

But the terminal is always saying that the sdk: command not found.
The idea is that this sdk is actually an alias defined in the sourced file from the first command(the ~/folder/env.sh), which is as following: alias sdk="python3 ${FOLDER_ENV}/sdk.py". Using a normal terminal, everything is fine if I first source the script, and then call the sdk command, but the task reacts as if the source command is not active.
I found other similar posts, but it seems that I'm already doing the right thing.
What could be the actual issue?
